# Is there any free extension available for designing products label or cover in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-connect

I am looking for a free product designer extension to design personalized photo covers for products like Bags,iPhone,Laptop,Mugs and tablets etc. If anyone knows free extension available in magento store or any other places, please provide me the link or if anyone has extension for designing product cover or label please provide with documentation or if any tutorial available for creating an extension like that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Years of experience tells me that wanting a drop-in free solution for this is ridiculously unreasonable. I don't mean that to be insulting to you at all, it's just that the level of integration necessary to achieve this is deep & complex.

Comment: @benmarks : I am not requesting a drop-in free solution. My requirement is different bro. I am asking a free designing extension for my customizing it to my project.

Comment: Okay, then you should clarify because *extension* in the context of "free product designer extension" has a very specific meaning in Magento.

Comment: Because I found commercial design tools only. Thats why I specified free product designer extension. Cool.

Comment: you can try this. i tried it and very good for customization  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-product-designer-1.html

Comment: @BalajiKandasamy did you found solution , if so please post an answer  with code.

Comment: No I didn't find a solution

Answer (score 17):

After searching for over a week - there is **presently** no **free** extension that meet your requirements. I suggest you look into some HTML5 Canvas javascript libraries to achieve at least the 'designer' portion of your requirement. There are currently a few dozen available freely. Here are a few of the most popular ones (according to # of Github watchers):

- http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS
- http://kineticjs.com/
- http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/
- http://fabricjs.com/

Here is an exhaustive list with features and # of github watchers, links, links to sites and demos; compiled by the author of Fabric.js, @kangax. This is a great feature matrix:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE#gid=0

I imagine it would be fairly easy for you to develop one of these libraries into a fully-featured drop-in extension and contribute it back to the community.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-product-designer-1.html  Very good. It is easy to customize and no encrypted code, where as other available extension are encrypted.  thanks