# Extension Needed for Product Customization

Tags: product, extensions, custom

I have been searching for an extension with the exact same function as this:
http://www.micro-scooters.co.uk/create-mini-micro/create-your-own-mini-micro-scooter.html

Unforunately, I couldn;t find in extensions section the same extension used in this website.
I know this is built with Magento Community edition.
Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I need this type extension for bed. could you please suggest the extension?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Magento 1.9.1 and custom swatches...

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-configurable-swatch.html%3FTocPath%3DProduct%2520Catalog|Swatches|_____0

You could almost hold it in custom Magento by this.

- Create a attribute for each option
- Create a attribute set with these options
- Create a simple product for each variant (could be 6 colors for 6 attributes, talking about 36 products)
- Create a configurable product and select each attribute
- Enable swatches for each attribute

Maybe you have to do something cool with extra images and some frontend javascript but hey, as close as I can get with standard Magento.

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom implementation and I've never come across a module that can do this this specific. Would be quite hard to do especially with the colored parts on the image.

This will probably require a lot of custom development, mostly on the frontend. I'd go with a bundled product with a bundle option for each of the colored parts and then use a mix of javascript and images to get the visual result

Answer (score 0):

That's seriously cool, yes you could do it but it would need custom dev over an existing extension. The standard way and your main problem will be the number of combinations, you will technically need a simple for each. You could do it with custom options but that requires another extension which applies images to them. That would potentially be 100s of combinations per product. To do it dynamically you need a product configurator which are expensive and a pain to setup, have work with them before and they do exist. There's no simple answer.

EDIT: found it, Doogma, except for the annoying emails they keep sending.

Answer (score 0):

There is presently no free extension that meet your requirements. I suggest you look into some HTML5 Canvas javascript libraries to achieve at least the 'designer' portion of your requirement. There are currently a few dozen available freely. Here are a few of the most popular ones (according to # of Github watchers):

```
http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS
http://kineticjs.com/
http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/
http://fabricjs.com/
```

Here is an exhaustive list with features and # of github watchers, links, links to sites and demos; compiled by the author of Fabric.js, @kangax. This is a great feature matrix:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE#gid=0

I imagine it would be fairly easy for you to develop one of these libraries into a fully-featured drop-in extension and contribute it back to the community.

Source [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/is-there-any-free-extension-available-for-designing-products-label-or-cover-in-m/%22Here%22) and Credit goes to @philwinkle

If you are looking for Magento2 extension for customizing or personalization the [Personalized Product by codedecorator](https://www.codedecorator.com/magento-2-personalized-products.html) may help you.