# Overlap Product image By uploaded image in product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, product-images, product-view, ui-library

We are displaying Product **image1** in site as below :

[image]

Now we are giving an option to upload **image2** from Product view page using below code, and what we want is **uploaded image2 should overlap on existed image1** like [here](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/apple/iphone-se/custom-iphone-se-cases/slim).

[image]

but now when we upload image2, image1 is overlapping on image2.

[image]

**code for upload image from product view page**

**html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div class ="up1234">
<input type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:canvas.getWidth(), height:canvas.getHeight()});
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
</script>
```

**Display Product image :**

```
<div id="case_canvas">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>   
</div>
```

We Tried below code, but it did't worked for us

```
#case_canvas {
     z-index:-1;
}
```

also once we click on "Add to cart" button we need to save uploaded image. after user place an order , the image should display in backend [ order view page ] as like `Default Magento File upload option`

Comment: i will give 50 bounty points if it worked for me.

Comment: I'd be impressed if you actually searched through the **whole** internet ;)

Comment: Paid turnkey solution: https://www.gomage.com/gomage-product-designer.html & relevant SO thread: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/is-there-any-free-extension-available-for-designing-products-label-or-cover-in-m

Comment: @B00MER please post your comment as answer, if there is no better answer i will accept yours :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paid for turnkey solution: https://www.gomage.com/gomage-product-designer.html

> After searching for over a week - there is **presently** no **free**
>   extension that meet your requirements. I suggest you look into some
>   HTML5 Canvas javascript libraries to achieve at least the 'designer'
>   portion of your requirement. There are currently a few dozen available
>   freely. Here are a few of the most popular ones (according to # of
>   Github watchers):
>
> - http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS
> - http://kineticjs.com/
> - http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/
> - http://fabricjs.com/
>
> Here is an exhaustive list with features and # of github watchers,
>   links, links to sites and demos; compiled by the author of Fabric.js,
>   @kangax. This is a great feature matrix:
>
> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE#gid=0
>
> I imagine it would be fairly easy for you to develop one of these
>   libraries into a fully-featured drop-in extension and contribute it
>   back to the community.

Source: [Is there any free extension available for designing products label or cover in magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/is-there-any-free-extension-available-for-designing-products-label-or-cover-in-m)